# Sequence $B_n=B_{n-1}\triangle A_n$ converges iff $A_n\rightarrow\phi$

Tags: measure-theory

> To prove (Sequence $B_n=B_{n-1}\triangle A_n$ converges iff $A_n\rightarrow\phi$) we can use to $B_{n-1}\triangle A_n$ to show that
> $$\tag{2}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}B_n=\phi$$
> $$\tag{1}B_n\space \text{are disjoints}$$

How are these two true?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I know that $
B_n\triangle B_{n-1}=(B_n|B_{n-1})\cup(B_{n-1}|B_n)=(B_n\cap B_{n-1}^c)\cup(B_{n-1}\cap B_n^c)
$ but  am not sure how to continue